# Adding UIView That Will Contain Input

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

So basically I have this page control view that I created that someone would segue into upon hitting the login or register button. So when it segues to that page view I attempted to setup a UIView on that page so a user can type in required info.

Code Below is how I have it implemented. Mind you this function is the target of the registration button. So even after running this no box appears? Any insight?

```
 func regSegue() {
    let page = UIPageViewController()
    page.view.backgroundColor = UIColor .white; //Set to any color.
    present(page, animated: true, completion: nil)

 // will create an inputs container view so users can enter credentials to register

    let regContainerView = U
    regContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    regContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    present(regContainerView, animated: true, completion: nil)

//need x,y,width, and height

    regContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

     regContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    regContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true

    regContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true

}
```

Comment: any help is appreciated

Comment: is it not possible?

Comment: Why can't you just add input fields through storyboard, all you want is making something by which user can register??

Comment: yeh but the problem is i haven't used storybord

Comment: Can you please show us some picture of how it should be?

Comment: How do i upload pics i am an uber noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var txtField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500.00, height: 30.00));

self.view.addSubview(txtField)
```

Thats how you can add one to your view .. Just an example. 
Hope so you will get an idea and do it your own way.

Comment: can i input this in my function and have a text field created in the new page that i make

Comment: add it in your page.view etc ... page.view.addSubview(textField) and then present it ..

Comment: and you can add line separators the same way?

Comment: so i couldn't do the same with a UIView

Comment: in order to add a line separator, you need to add a UIView of height 1 and give it some color ...

Comment: would it be easier to add a UIView

Comment: i appreciate everything i try to do things without storyboards and this helps alot

Comment: But I will recommend you to use storyboard ..You will learn and understand the behaviour of the things ..

Comment: If I do it with storyboards or make small tweaks it'll be harder to do seeing as storyboards can get complicated if there are a lot of controllers.

Comment: Not that was not the case .. Storyboard is created for our ease ..It is there so we can separate ui layer and code from each other unless we need to do something that is not achievable ..

Comment: btw i am also a newbie .. :)